# C++ Functions as parameters

Tags: c#, c++, dll, parameters, visual-c#-express-2010

I have a DLL containing C++ code, which works perfectly in Visual C#. When I create a fucton in the C++ DLL, it shows up in Visual C# and I call it, even with parameters. However, when I add a function pointer as one of the parameters in the C++ DLL, it cannot be found by Visual C#.

C++ Functions:

```
 int TEST(int *func) // Works fine and shows up in visual C#.
 { 
     return 0;
 } 

int TEST2(int (*func)()) // Works, however doesn't show up in Visual C#
{
     return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

When I call TEST2 from C#, I get the error: `'TEST2' is not supported by the language`

Comment: What do you mean by "it cannot be found by Visual C#?"

Comment: While the above is a valid function declaration, I suspect you meant `int (*func)()`, i.e. pointer to a function returning int. As written, the argument type is a function returning `int*` (which in that context means a pointer to a function returning `int*`).

Answer (score 2):

The function pointer argument should be declared like this:

```
int TEST2(int (*func)()) { /*...*/ }
```

Comment: The missing parentheses might be intentional if the goal is to take as input a function that takes no arguments and returns an `int*`.  From the question I can't tell whether or not this was the goal.

Comment: @templatetypedef: In that case it'd be `int * (*func)()`.

Comment: @SamH: Using a function type as function argument type is valid and equivalent to using a pointer to that function type in that context.

Comment: I can only call the function from C# if there are no function parameters.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Not necessarily, the standard states that an argument of type *function* is converted to *function pointer* (as part of the conversions that include *array decay*), that is, `void f( void g() )` is converted by the compiler into `void f( void (*g)() )` while processing the function declaration, in a similar way that `void f( int a[1] )` gets converted to `void f( int *a )`. Still I agree that the user most probably wants to have a pointer to a function thar returns a plain `int`

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you need parenthesis around `*func` to tell the compiler that *func is a pointer to a function `int (*func)()` instead of `int *(*func)()` which is what you have.